# Trigger in Microsoft Fabric Data Warehouse

Tags: triggers, microsoft-fabric

I have a date table in a Microsoft Fabric Data Warehouse. This table contains 3 columns: year, quarter, and period, where the last one has a format 'YYYY/QUARTER'. This table will be linked in the model to another sales table which also has a period column with the same structure as the date table. I would like to know if it's possible that when I add data to the sales table, the dates in the date table are automatically populated based on this new data that was added in the sales table. I tried to create a trigger but I'm getting the error: 'CREATE/ALTER TRIGGER is not supported.' Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no triggers.  Whatever process you use to load the fact table (stored procedure, or pipeline) should rebuild the date table after the load.

Fabric DW is a big data MPP engine, so doesn't support enforced unique constraints, foreign keys, triggers, etc.

So you have to maintain and enforce these sorts of things in your ETL processes.